# Why this program is output Yes, while it should either have thrown error or NO

Tags: c, types, integer, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Here a + b is -14 which should have been lesser than 'a' and hence should have printed NO but it printed yes.

```
unsigned int a = 6;
int b = -20;

if((a+b)  > a){
    printf("Yes");
} else {
    printf("NO");
}

return 1;
```

Comment: Why exactly are you specifying that a is an unsigned int? Is there any need for you to do so?

Answer (score 2):

According to the C Standard (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause
> conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to
> determine a common real type for the operands and result. For the
> specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
> domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real
> type. Unless explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also
> the corresponding real type of the result, whose type domain is the
> type domain of the operands if they are the same, and complex
> otherwise. This pattern is called **the usual arithmetic conversions**:
>
> ...
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
> greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
> the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
> operand with unsigned integer type.

Types `unsigned int` and `int` have the same rank.

Thus the value of the variable `b` from your example is interpreted as an unsigned value.

If to use the correct conversion specifier `%u` for the expression `( a + b )` in a function call of `printf` then you might get

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int a = 6;
    int b = -20;
    
    printf( "a + b = %u\n", a + b );
    
    return 0;
}


a + b = 4294967282
```

Comment: Good catch on the unsigned int

Answer (score 0):

You compare signed with unsigned. As all values of unsigned cannot be accommodated in the signed so the the signed value is converted to unsigned and is much larger than 6